# Check if the variable is empty or not set

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Run APP deployment $LC_APP_URL"
LC_CODE=$(
  docker run --rm --name argocd-test \
    -e DO_AC=$DO_AC \
    -e K8S_CLUSTER=k8s-databaker-io \
    -e ARGO_SERVER=cd.databaker.io \
    -e ARGO_USERNAME="$ARGO_USERNAME" \
    -e ARGO_PW="$ARGO_PW" \
    -e IMAGE_URL=hub.databaker.io/ui/argo-ui-test \
    -e IMAGE_VERSION=0.1.2 \
    -e CHARTS_URL=gitlab.com/databaker.io/charts.git \
    -e GITOPS_URL=gitlab.com/databaker.io/gitops.git \
    -e APP_TYPE=ui \
    -e APP=argo-ui-test \
    -e APP_URL="$LC_APP_URL" \
    -e APP_TLS_SECRET="dev-cert-staging" \
    -e GIT_USER="$GIT_USER" \
    -e GIT_AT=$GIT_AT \
    -e NAMESPACE=dev \
    "$LC_IMAGE_NAME" /sh/main.sh
  echo $?
)

echo "????????????????????????? $LC_CODE"

if [ -z "$LC_CODE" ]; then
  echo "Exit"
  exit 1
fi

if [ "$LC_CODE" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Run deployment failed"
  exit 1
fi
```

That should go into `if [ -z "$LC_CODE" ];` statement and print `Exit`. The `$LC_CODE` is empty, because the statement `echo "????????????????????????? $LC_CODE"` shows `?????????????????????????` .

How to validate, if `$LC_CODE` is set or empty?

Comment: Instead of `echo` try: `declare -p LC_CODE` to check a variable

Comment: Don't even bother.  Just do `if ! docker ...`.  Or even just `docker ... || exit`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't inadvertently put a backslash after `/sh/main.sh` as well? If you did, then `echo` and `$?` would be two additional arguments to `docker` that it (or rather, `main.sh`) ignores.

Comment: Does your script use DOS line endings? If so, then the value of `LC_CODE` is a single carriage return, not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
if [ "$LC_CODE" == "" ]; then
  echo "Exit"
  exit 1
fi
```

I think you're variable is set but string is empty